# Extracting dict keys from values

Tags: dictionary, key-value-store

I am still learning about python and I face some trouble extracting data from a dict. I need to create a loop which check each values and extract the keys. So for this code I need to find the nice students. I am stuck at line 3 #blank.
How do i go about this?
Thanks in advance

```
class = {"James":"naughty", "Lisa":"nice", "Bryan":"nice"}
for student in class:
    if #blank:
        print("Hello, "+student+" students!")
else:
    print("odd")
```

Answer (score 0):

Uses dictionary methods "keys(), values(), items()":

```
def get_students_by_criteria(student_class, criteria):

    students = []

    for candidate, value in student_class.items():
        if value == criteria:
            students.append(candidate)

    return students

my_class = {"James":"naughty", "Lisa":"nice", "Bryan":"nice"}


print(get_students_by_criteria(my_class, "nice"))
```

Warning to the word "class" it is a keyword reserved for python programming oriented object